# Explain why, if $P$ is equivalent to $Q$, then $\sim P$ is equivalent to $\sim Q$?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

In "[A Transition to Advanced Mathematics](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/1285463269)", the 8th edition, for chapter 1 problem 8 (c), I must explain why the following is true:

> If $P$ is equivalent to $Q$, then $\sim P$ is equivalent to $\sim Q$

(Note in the chapter one we only learned about $\sim$, $\land$, $\lor$, and truth values with truth tables)

### Attempt

$\sim P$ has the opposite truth value of $P$, and $P$ is equivalent to $Q$. Therefore, $\sim P$ has the opposite truth value as $Q$. Since $\sim P$ has the opposite truth value as $Q$, and $Q$ has the opposite truth value as $\sim Q$, we get $\sim P$ has the same truth value as $\sim Q$. Therefore, $\sim P$ is equivalent to $\sim Q$.

**Question:** Is my attempt correct? If so, how can it be improved? If not, what is the correct answer?

Comment: Do you have a definition of "equivalent" or only an informal notion?  Your argument is okay as an informal explanation, but if "equivalent" has a definition, yiu'd better use it.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Another, more pedestrian approach is to write out the truth-tables of $P\leftrightarrow Q$ and $\sim P \leftrightarrow \sim Q$ and note that they are the same.

Comment: @MJD In the book, "equivalent" means the propositional statements must have the same truth tables.

Comment: It is simpler to draw a truth table that to describe it with words.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry regarding the last comment. In chapter 1 problem 8, only part a) has a solution in the answer key; however, the solution is by word rather than a truth table.